# magento database structure help regarding reviews

Tags: database, magento, database-design

i am building a script that will import reviews into magento, i had a look at the table structure and i found these tables

```
review
review_detail
review_entity
review_entity_summary
review_status
review_store
```

i understood purpose and structure of all the tables but i was unable to understand the following table

```
review_entity_summary
```

can any one explain the purpose of this table and do i need to update this table while inserting new reviews, and if yes then which values i need to use to update this?

Comment: I have written a detailed article on table structure for product reviews - https://blog.magepsycho.com/import-product-reviews-in-magento-via-sql/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `review_entity_summary` table contains some summation raiting info about every product. The main aim of this table is easy access to the overage raiting and count of reviews on the product listing page.

After inserting new reviews you should update this table. 
I think you should run the '`$review->aggregate();`' after inserting.